# exposing part of my parse.com api to other developers via ouath 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, parse-platform, publisher

It's now trivial to create a web app that sits atop Parse.com. Now that I have this webapp, I want to expose parts of it to other developers via an oauth accesible api. So, they can develop an app that lets my site users 'give them permission' via oauth and they can now access the api.

How would I start going about doing this?

Update: After @Mubix response, I felt the following clarification would help

Currently I am accessing Parse from the server via a REST api, to get around any javascript security issues re:api keys etc. So, the api would be served of a server other than Parse. Also, the server code is in javascript / nodejs. I came across https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize which seems a likely candidate, was wondering how others are doing it and if anyone has actually gone a further step and integrated Parse access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm .. Intereesting question!

**Legal:**
First of all their [ToS](https://parse.com/about/terms) doesn't seem to prohibit what you are trying to do but you should read it carefully before you start.

**Implementation:**
While parse doesn't provide feature to build your own APIs you could implement something yourself. You could treat the third party developers as users of your app. And you can use the [ACL](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.ACL.html) to control access.

**Problems:**

- I don't see any way to implement oAuth entirely within parse.
- How will third party apps access your API? Ideally you would like them to use a REST interface but with the parse.com REST API you won't be able to manage access to different parts of your data.

**Conclusion:**
It seems like too much trouble to implement the API entirely within parse. I would suggest that you write a thin API layer that takes care of auth and uses parse as the backend. You can use one of the service side [libraries](https://www.parse.com/docs/api_libraries) available for parse. eg. [PHP Library](https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library), [Node Parse](https://github.com/Leveton/node-parse-api).

Comment: I think an api-layer on a separate server will definitely be the way to go. My question - is there some such codebase that one can simply snap-in and configure so one gets all the oauth-goodness and than can expose only portions of the Parse-db.

Comment: AFAIK, There is no plug and play framework to get what you want. In the past I have implemented APIs with ZF in PHP. Today I might consider Expressjs and Passportjs. In any case you will easily get drop-in components for oAuth and REST API but you will have to write the CRUD code for parse yourself.